# Complex exponential has $1$ as Lipschitz constant.

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

(In the following, Lipschitz constant does not mean "best Lipschitz constant".)

I've just read this in a book that I highly regard:

> Moreover, by mean value theorem, $u\to e^{iu}$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$.

How does the author infer this from the mean value theorem ? The theorem applies only for real-valued functions.

The mean value theorem shows nontheless that $\sin$ and $\cos$ have Lipschitz constant $1$, and therefore $u\to e^{iu}$ has Lipschitz constant $2$.

How can this be lowered  to $1$ ?

Comment: There is a vector valued version of MVT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $a \le b$.

$$|e^{ib} - e^{ia}| = \left|\int_a^b ie^{it}\,dt\right|\le \int_a^b |ie^{it}|\,dt  = b -a.$$

Comment: Nicely done! I don't know why the author referred to the mean value theorem.